# How to check if DVD/CD is 32bit or 64bit on linux

Tags: linux, command-line

Is there any command on linux to check if CD or DVD is 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: What do you mean by "32 bit" and "64 bit" in this context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A CD or DVD is not really 32 bits or 64 bits. However, it may contain a 64 bit program. The linux utility `file` can tell you more about an executable.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a live distro running you can check the running version with `uname -a`